# matlab osm webread slow

Tags: matlab, openstreetmap

i am using Matlab's webread() function to download openstreetmap osm files.
My goal is to write an application that downloads osm data, parses it in Matlab, then reads out coordinate values and plots them.

Unfortunately, the overall code seems to run pretty slow, and running the profiler showed that most of the runtime comes from using the webread() function, even though the requested .osm are comparatively small (<500kb) and downloaded via Browser within a fraction of the time the function uses.

What can i do to speed up the downloading process? Is it recommended to use the webread function for this task at all? I was also considering downloading the files by using another language/a bash application that can be called from within Matlab.

EDIT: osm data is downloaded as XML file

Comment: Is the downloaded data JSON? If so, it's likely the conversion from JSON to a struct that is the bottleneck.

Comment: the downloaded data is in xml format, which is then imported as a raw string and parsed using regular expressions

Comment: Consider using an offline map instead. Downloading these files on the fly will always be slow. It will also stress the download servers.